How to set Partitioned attribute for all cookies in Java?
As part of adapting to the phase-out of third-party cookies, we would like to adopt Cookies Having Independent Partitioned State (CHIPS) across our whole application. How can we easily set the new Partitioned attribute for all cookies?
We use Java 20 but the Cookie class has not a SetPartitioned function.

Which Cookie class are you using? jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie? If so, you might be able to use setAttribute.

"Partitioned" is not supported along with all major browsers so neither it is supported in most of cookie creation libraries.
In our spring boot application we had to deal with it by adding it manually like this:
ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("cookie", value)
                .sameSite("None")
                .secure(true)
                .httpOnly(true)
                ...
                .build();

String cookieString = cookie + "; Partitioned";
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookieString);


As you can see we append to cookie string word Partitioned at the very end. I think you can do the same in your app.
